# List comprehension not work out right

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

```
 def first_and_last(list_1):
    new_list = [i for i in list_1 if i ==(list_1[0] or list_1[len(list_1 - 1)])]
    return new_list
```

after i enter the sequence of numbers, the output stays the same as the original list. I think there would be something wrong with my list comprehension

```
a= [input("Enter a sequence of numbers separated by commas :")]

b = first_and_last(a)
print (b)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems that i have found:

1)

```
a = [input("Enter a sequence of numbers separated by commas :")]
```

This will give you a list containing the entire string as a single element, but not individual elements. For example, on executing this string you will get...

```
a = ['1,2,3,4,5']
```

to resolve this you need take the string input and split it on ","

```
a = input("Enter a sequence of numbers separated by commas :").split(",")
```

2)

The conditional filter used in list comprehension is wrong..

```
2 or 3 = 2
3 or 2 = 3
0 or 2 = 2
2 or 0 = 2
```

If there is a "0" element it returns the other non zero element, if both are non zero it returns the first one, hence

if my list was...

```
a = [1 , 2 , 3]
b = first_and_last(a)
print(b)
```

this would result in

```
b = [3]
```

Hence the right condition or approach would be

```
new_list = [i for i in list_1 if i == list_1[0] or i == list_1[len(list_1 - 1)]]
```

or

```
b = list()
b.append(a[0])
b.append(a[len(a)-1])
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the condition filter part in part 2 ,especially about the 0 one.

Comment: when you are constructing your list through list comprehension,
 ` (list_1[0] or list_1[len(list_1)-1])`
will give you list_1[0] if its a non zero element, effectively its equivalent  to 

` i == list_[0]`

Comment: why does this happen? Have any source like any website to help me understand more? Thank you for replying.

Comment: What is believe is how it is evaluated, 0 - False , non zero - True 
if the first element is a non zero element then its gives the first element, since its true

Similarly "and" even if the first element is non zero it checks the last element, only if that is non zero it returns that last element 

eg:  0 or 2 or 0 = 2 , 3 and 2 = 2 , 0 and 2 = 0 ,

Comment: Thanks, now i understand.

Answer (score 0):

The following output of my python console might already clarify a few things:

```
>>> new_list = [input()]
1, 2, 3, 4
>>> new_list
[(1, 2, 3, 4)]
>>> l = [i for i in new_list if i==(new_list[0] or new_list[-1])]
>>> l
[(1, 2, 3, 4)]
>>> new_list[-1]
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

You have a list, but your list `a` has only one element. In my example, `a` only contains the element `(1, 2, 3, 4)`.
When you do your list comprehension, you take the element iff it equals the first or last element - which it does. And there's no error because the index `-1` just stands for the last element in your list.

You can turn the input tuple into a list:

```
>>> list(input())
1, 2, 3, 4
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Then, your list comprehension could work.
I'm not sure if your syntax for the if works though. I would go with

```
>>> li = list(input())
1, 2, -3, 4
>>> new_list = [i for i in li if (li[0]==i or i==li[-1])]
>>> new_list
[1, 4]
>>> lix = list(input())
1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2
>>> other_list = [i for i in lix if (lix[0]==i or i==lix[-1])]
>>> other_list
[1, 1, 2, 2]
```

If you use your if syntax, what you're testing is whether a element equals `(li[0] or li[-1])`. I believe that this will always either be 0 or 1, because it is a boolean expression.

```
>>> other_list = [i for i in lix if i==(lix[0] or lix[-1])]
>>> other_list
[1, 1]
```

I tested this in `python 2.7.14` so your syntax might vary slightly.

Comment: Note that `i == (A or B)` is normally wrong. And should be `i == A or i ==  B` or `i in (A, B)`.

Comment: @DanD. Is it more wrong than just what I pointed out about it being evaluated as a boolean expression? (Elegant way of writing it, `i in (A, B)`, I got to remember that)

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to split the string into a list.
2. You can simplify your condition.

Code:

```
def first_and_last(input):
  list = input.split(',')
  match = list[0], list[-1]
  return [i for i in list if i in match]
```